# Usar conexión PDO para hacer Sentencias Preparadas [PHP y MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

¿Alguien puede decirme si es correcto usar la siguiente conexión PDO para hacer un INSERT en Consultas Preparadas?

**Conexión PDO:**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','user');
define('DBPASS','pass');
define('DBNAME','name');

try {

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}
?>
```

Si es posible hacerlo así, ¿**Debería reemplazar "$con" por la variable "$db"**?:

```
$sent_prep =$con->prepare($sql);
```

Antes usaba una conexión normal, y quiero reemplazarla por esa conexión PDO. Quiero saber si es suficiente con reemplazar las variables anteriores.

Comment: la conexión muestrala completa, al menos yo si necesito ver si esta sola o dentr de una función

Comment: @shadow Listo, he añadido todo.

Comment: `$con` o `$db`  serían solamente variables que representarían a tu objeto de conexión. Si en este contexto escribes esto: `$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);` lo lógico es que uses `$db` en todo, porque el objeto de conexión va a quedar asignado a `$db`. Si tienes un script con código donde usas `$con`, entonces cambia las variables al principio para no tener que cambiar todo en el script. O sea, haz esto: `$con = new PDO("...."); $con->setAttribute(...); $con->setAttribute(...);`

Comment: Entonces, solo tendría que añadir esta parte: `$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);` Con las variables que definen los datos de la conexión, y luego reemplazar `$con` por `$db` o viceversa.

Comment: Correcto. Si te decides por `$db`, todo lo que se refiera a la conexión debe ser cambiado por `$db` y si te decides por `$con`, lo mismo, todo lo que haga referencia a la conexión debe estar escrito como `$con`... Ah por cierto, puedes pasar los atributos como un array de opciones en el constructor, así creas el objeto configurado de una vez por todas y no tienes que manipularlo más con los `setAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que tienes una variable llamada `$db` que almacena la conexión, un ejemplo para las cobnsultas preparadas debería ser así

```
$id = 12;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = :id"; 
$procesaConsulta = $db->prepare($sql);
$procesaConsulta->execute([':id' => $id]);
```

Donde notas que:

1. Recibo el valor de una variable llamada `$id` que en la consulta indico con un marcador de nombre `:id`
2. Hago uso del método `prepare()` para preparar la consulta que se lamacena en `$sql`
3. Dentro de un array asociativo paso en el `execute()` el marcador de nombre y la variable `$id`

Lo anterior es por ejemplo si vas a utilizar datos dinámicos es decir que envia el usuario, si por el contrario es una consulta que no procesa ningún parámetro enviado por el usuario entonces debería verse así:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios"; 
$procesaConsulta = $db->query($sql);
```

> Y si como notas sigo haciendo uso de `$db` como la variable que me
>   permite acceder a la conexión, estaría de mas igualar esa variable con
>   otra para acceder a dicha conexión; es decir no es necesario